# How to use sub query in SQL?

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

I have 4 tables :

`Travelers (TravelerID,FirstName,LastName)`

`Guides(GuideID,FirstName,LastName)`

`Locations(LocationID,LocationName)`

`Trips(TravelerID,GuideID,LocationID,Stars,StartDate,ReturnDate)`

I want to return per guide the name of location which he guided the maximum number of  travelers .

I have tried to use this sub query but it doesn't work :

```
SELECT G.FirstName,L.LocationName,count(distinct(TravelerID))as number_of_travelers_per_guide 
FROM Guides AS G 
LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
GROUP BY G.FirstName,L.LocationName 
HAVING max((SELECT T1.number_of_travelers_per_guide 
            FROM Trips AS T1 
            WHERE T.GuideID=T1.GuideID));
```

I will appreciate any help

Comment: Doesn't work - can you be a bit more precise.

Comment: sql returns me : Unknown column "T1.number_of_travelers_per_guide" in "field list"

Comment: You can't use aliases in subqueries

Comment: can you please tell me i should i do it?

Comment: @linda, Just to be clear, do you mean "per guide, the location where he has accompanied the highest number of separate individuals across all time" (i.e. how many different people have visited a particular place once or more in the past, and who was their guide), or do you mean "per guide, the location where he has accompanied the largest party of individuals as part of a single trip" (i.e. how many people have visited a place together on a single trip, and who was their guide)?

Comment: i meant "how many different people have visited a particular place once or more in the past, and who was their guide"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is a real pain in MySQL, because pre v 8 versions have neither CTEs nor window functions.  One method uses variables:

```
SELECT gl.*
FROM (SELECT gl.*,
             (@rn := if(@g = gl.FirstName, @rn + 1,
                        if(@g := gl.FirstName, 1, 1)
                       )
             ) as rn
      FROM (SELECT G.FirstName, L.LocationName, count(distinct TravelerID) as number_of_travelers_per_guide 
            FROM Guides G LEFT JOIN
                 Trips T
                 USING (GuideID) LEFT JOIN
                 Locations L
                 USING (LocationID)
            GROUP BY G.FirstName, L.LocationName 
            ORDER BY G.FirstName, number_of_travelers_per_guide DESC
           ) gl CROSS JOIN
           (SELECT @g := '', @rn := -1) params
      ) gl
WHERE rn = 1;
```

I wouldn't stress out on understanding variables in MySQL.  Instead, learn about `row_number()`, `rank()`, and `dense_rank()` -- those are the right way to solve the problem in almost all databases.

Comment: thanks! but unfortunately i need to solve this in sql

Comment: @linda this is mysql syntax what sql are you referring to?

Comment: @Gordon Linoff your code ia amazing! but im not aloud to use variables.can you help me and write the same without variables?

Answer (score 1):

try using the complete function and not the alis

```
SELECT G.FirstName,L.LocationName, count(distinct T.TravelerID ) as number_of_travelers_per_guide 
FROM Guides AS G 
LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
GROUP BY G.FirstName,L.LocationName 
HAVING count(distinct TravelerID ) = ( 
            select max(my_count) from (SELECT count(distinct T.TravelerID) my_count
            FROM Guides AS G 
            LEFT JOIN Trips AS T USING (GuideID) 
            LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (LocationID)
            GROUP BY G.FirstName, L.LocationName ) my_t );
```

Comment: sql returns : "you have an error in your SQL syntax"

Comment: first of all thank you very much for the help! second, now its works but it returns only 2 guides instead of all the list of the guides altough there is "left join"

Comment: the having filter the resulting rows this mean that ilter also the returned  values for left join

Comment: so where should i put the sub query if i want to return all the list of guides? even if they didnt have any travelers they guided?

Comment: first you should remove the having clause .. but this seem a new question to me.. in SO is fair post a single question by time and post the new one as well described new question post

Comment: if it is possible it will be very nice if you can tell me i should i write the code so i will have a list of all the guides and the name of the location where they guided the maximum number of travelers (if traveler number 1 appears twice it will consider only one)  .i just cant figure it out by myself

Comment: i will appreciate  your help very much

Comment: i dont know how to write a code that will return a list of all the guides (even if they didnt have travelers at all ) .can you please help me

Comment: as  suggested in the previous comment  .. post a new question with the code you have  .. a proper data sample the actual result and the result you need .. don't update this question ..add a new one so the SO community can help you  ..

Comment: i post new question i will appreciate if you will help me

Answer (score 0):

If CTEs and analytic functions cannot be used, I think you'd be looking at something like the following. There is a danger however that if a guide has two equal-ranking locations, two or more rows will be returned for that guide instead of just one.

```
SELECT
    G.FirstName
    ,L.LocationName
    ,guide_stats.traveler_count

FROM
    (
        SELECT
            GuideID
            ,LocationID
            ,COUNT(DISTINCT TravelerID) AS traveler_count

        FROM Trips
        GROUP BY GuideID, LocationID

    ) AS guide_stats

INNER JOIN
    (
        SELECT 
            guide_stats_for_max.GuideID
            ,MAX(guide_stats_for_max.traveler_count) AS max_traveler_count

        FROM
        (
            SELECT
                GuideID
                ,LocationID
                ,COUNT(DISTINCT TravelerID) AS traveler_count

            FROM Trips
            GROUP BY GuideID, LocationID

        ) AS guide_stats_for_max

        GROUP BY GuideID

    ) AS guide_max
    ON (guide_stats.GuideID = guide_max.GuideID)
    AND (guide_stats.traveler_count = guide_max.max_traveler_count)

LEFT JOIN Guides    AS G USING (guide_stats.GuideID)
LEFT JOIN Locations AS L USING (guide_stats.LocationID)
```

Note I've written this code without testing - please excuse small errors.

Comment: hi , 
sql returns "column 'GuideID' in form clause is ambiguous" i dont undertand what it means

Comment: @linda, I've adjusted it slightly to add extra qualifiers. I don't have a MySQL environment, so I can't test the code, and unfortunately it's not my normal SQL language.